# Fill cell in table with line pattern

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have some empty cells in a table and I want to fill those with some sort of pattern to express that it is supposed to be empty (something more elegant than filling it with a ---). I have been googling for a while but I only find ways to fill with solid colors, I'd like to use a pattern of parallel diagonal lines, like the picture below, or something similar.

I know how to fill other shapes, but I was wondering if there was something similar for tables.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use a hatch in Word.

1. Select the cell(s) you want to change
2. Right click and select `Boarders and Shading`
3. Click on the `Shading` tab
4. Under `Patterns` open the `Style` drop down and pick the hatch you want. The hatches are after the transparency settings.
5. In the `Apply To:` box select `Cell`

[image: Border and Shading Box]

Comment: Well hidden. Unfortunately, these are slightly different styles than in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I use diagonal lines across the cell to indicate is was not used.

1. Select the cell(s) you want to change
2. Right click and select `Boarders and shading`
3. Change the `Apply to:` to `Cell`
4. Click the diagonal boarder button
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Results in a diagonal line through the cell. You can change the type of line and pattern to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking for something more complex, my bad for not being clear. I have edited the original question with an example, maybe you know how it could be done?

Comment: Yes, those details would have been good to know when I answered. You are looking for the fill format for the cells which is on the `Shading` tab of the window above. Click the `Style:` drop down and scroll to the bottom to select the pattern you want.